# Retrieving Entity Reference Fields programmatically

Tags: entities, database

i am stuck retrieving an entity reference fields the correct way.
All i tried gave me an error or and empty array...

What you see here is my node object that holds the data (copied from the DSM output):

```
... (Object) stdClass
vid (String, 2 characters ) 64
uid (String, 1 characters ) 8
type (String, 6 characters ) people
    field_people_publications (Array, 1 element) 
       und (Array, 3 elements) 
          0 (Array, 1 element)
             target_id (String, 3 characters ) 839
          1 (Array, 1 element)
             target_id (String, 3 characters ) 840
          3 (Array, 1 element)
             target_id (String, 3 characters ) 841
```

Documentiontion on using entity reference fields programmatically seems very very rare. I have noch found much that helped me out.

Related to the DSM output above:

How do i retrieve the entity reference field 'field_people_publications' from the node-ID #64?

What are those 'target_id' about? Inside the HTML view these are checkboxes with 5 options available. This is quite confusing.

Can you give give me a helping hand?
What i wanted to do is to modify these options to some other values and save them again.

Comment: Could you add the code you're trying that doesn't work? Rather than explain the entirety of accessing field with an `EntityMetadataWrapper`, it would be much simpler to debug your specific code. Make sure you [read the docs](https://drupal.org/node/1021556) as well, they explain it pretty well

Comment: Thanks dude. I'll give it a try and will add some working/not working code here shortly.